# Не работает @media screen когда их много

Tags: css3, css

Как можно решить эту проблему? у меня их около 15. В разные стили разделял всеравно не работает. Самое главное при ресайзе через браузер работает, а если попробовать через смартфон то не работает.

UPD. на айфоне все работает, а через samsung galaxy y с шириной 320, уже не работает

Comment: min 1600
@media screen and (min-width: 1230px) and (max-width: 1599px)
@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1230px)
@media screen  and (max-width: 1000px)
Ну и эти. 
600-768
480-600
340-480
300-340

И вот на мобилах 300-340 упорно не хочет работать.

Comment: Примерно так должна выглядеть структура ваших запросов:

    @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
        /* Стили для разрешения 1280px и меньше */
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        /* Стили для разрешения 1024px и меньше */
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        /* Стили для разрешения 768px и меньше */
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        /* Стили для разрешения 600px и меньше */
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        /* Стили для разрешения 480px и меньше */
    }

Comment: Всё работает, только div'ы не переносятся как надо. На мобильных открывает точно так же как и с пк, а по задумке, блоки должны вниз спускаться, всё работало до поры до времени

Comment: @reddyk, значит либо неправильная структура, либо проблемы в приоритетности правил.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте добавить такой мета-тег:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

И как у вас идут media-запросы? Должно быть от большего к меньшему.

*Обновление*

И вообще 15 media-запросов это много. Ограничтесь следующими отрезками:

```
320-480
480-600
600-768
768-1024
1024-...
```

Этого будет более чем достаточно. Или посмотрите в сторону отзывчивого дизайна, когда макет изменяется не только за счет media-запросов, но и за счет своей "резиновости".

Comment: стоит <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

от большего к меньшему не знал, у меня там бардак) сейчас попробую

Answer (score -1):

Вы допускаете ошибку большую
В медиа запросах надо указывать интервал от минимального до максимального, у вас же просто указаны максимальные.
просто в каждом медиа укажите интервалы.
Подумайте, насколькоаптуально 15 штук?
Как уже написано выше, лучше брать основные:

- Очень маленькие устройства Телефоны (<768px)
- Маленькие устройства Планшеты (≥768px)
- Средние устройства Компьютеры (≥992px)
- Большие устройства Компьютеры (≥1200px)

Comment: Вы уверены?  Я просмотрев сайты которые стоят очень очень дорого, которые делали самые лучшие специалисты и  там  такого почему-то  не видел. Я сам по логике сначала подумал что нужно делать так как и вы описываете, но там почему то так не делают.